# Ajax is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax is Not Working : I want to update one record using Code Igniter framework. when i passing po_id to below url. my ajax is not working. but without passing id my below ajax is working.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo base_url('inventory_c/view_purchase_update/'.$result->po_id);?>">Update</a>
```

Controller:

```
public function view_purchase_update() {
      $data['pitems'] = $this->inventory_m->purchase_items_update($po_id);
      $data['sname']  = $this->inventory_m->getsuppname($supplier_id);
      $data['sid'] = $this->inventory_m->getsuppid($po_id);      
      $this->load->view('superadmin/editable_purchase_update',$data);     
}
```

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_temp_purchase",
      cache: false,
      data: 'itemnum='+itemnum+'&itemname='+itemname+'&costprice='+costprice+'&quantity='+quantity+'&customer_id='+customer_id+'&sales='+sales,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(returnhtml) {

      }
});
```

Comment: u must need to define full url here `url: "add_temp_purchase",` along with controller name: maybe: `url: "add_temp_purchase/view_purchase_update",`

Comment: when you click the `update` its bring you to `view_purchase_update` method. So what you suppose to do with AJAX ??

Comment: where is your add_temp_purchase function?

Comment: public function add_temp_purchase() 
 {
    
       echo $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
 
          $add_temp_purchase = array( 
               'item_id' => $item_id,
      'item_name' => $item_name,
      'cost_price' => $costprice,
     );
      
           $this->db->insert('order_taken_list', $add_temp_purchase);
              
    if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1) 
    {
     echo "Temp Data Inserted";
     }
     else{
     echo "Wrong Move";
         }
     
 }

Comment: without passing any id to url ajax is working, but when i passing id its not working

Answer (score 0):

When sending data with Ajax mind that it's JSON formatted.

What you can do is below:

```
$.post( "add_temp_purchase", { 
      itemnum: itemnum, 
      itemname: itemname,
      costprice: costprice,
      quantity: quantity,
      customer_id: customer_id,
      sales: sales
}).success(function( data ) {
     alert( "success" );
});
```

In your controller you would have the follwing

```
public function postData() {
     $postData = $this->input->post();
     $itemNum = $postData['itemnum'];
     #etc....
}
```

Aswell can you confirm you can print out `$result->po_id` in your view? 
It seems that you never parse that to the view, in your controller you should do the following to make sure you have this

```
public function view_purchase_update() {
  $data['pitems'] = $this->inventory_m->purchase_items_update($po_id);
  $data['sname']  = $this->inventory_m->getsuppname($supplier_id);
  $data['sid'] = $this->inventory_m->getsuppid($po_id);   
  $data['po_id'] = $po_id;
  $this->load->view('superadmin/editable_purchase_update',$data);     
}
```

Then in your view you will use it like this

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="<?= base_url('inventory_c/view_purchase_update/'.$po_id);?>">Update</a>
```

Comment: yes i have get my previous data using id. want to edit the data and delete using db with help of codeigniter.

Comment: without id data is added in db..with help of ajax

Comment: Check your dev tools of your browser, you should see the ajax call under your network tab and you'll see some response.

Comment: how to check the dev tools

Comment: getting Internal Server Error 500

Comment: how to resolve this error can anyone pls help me to find out these error.

Comment: If you click on the 500 error in your network tab and select "preview" you are most likely to read the error, if not I'd suggest turning on the error log of CodeIgniter and look inside the error log, that will have the exact error